# My question closed as a duplicate of another question with is not at all the same except for a couple of similarities

Tags: discussion

I posted this question - [While creating a password for an Admin user, I get a scary message "will lose all EFS-encrypted files, personal certs & stored passwords"](https://superuser.com/questions/1744239/while-creating-a-password-for-an-admin-user-i-get-a-scary-message-will-lose-al)

It got closed as a duplicate of [Accessing EFS-encrypted files after resetting Windows password](https://superuser.com/questions/767239/accessing-efs-encrypted-files-after-resetting-windows-password)

These are 2 are not at all the same question & neither does the other answer of any help to me.

- My question is about while changing Windows Password using a particular method, you get a scary message about losing your EFS-encrypted data & other saved passwords & certs.
- The other question is about what to do after you have lost your EFS encrypted data because of changing the password using that particular password. I also asked if I would lose my Firefox saved passwords etc.

I got an excellent answer to my question - which covered multiple things

- What is the meaning of the message
- How I will probably not lose my Firefox saved passwords
- The answer also gave me a way to avoid this whole scenario by changing password in a different way to avoid losing anything. I used this method to changing my password & avoid running into the scenario.

My question was closed as a dup of the other (different) question. But luckily someone had answered it. And I was able to upvote & accept the answer.

But I don't think this is a dup of that particular question. And the answer is very useful.

So I think the question should be reopened - won't make a diff since I have already accepted the answer. But just as a matter of principle, it should be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to say here - I agree its not a duplicate, and someone else already voted, and as such, I reopened it.